# Best practice for deleting vector of pointers while iterating

Tags: c++, vector

When iterating through an STL::vector of pointers, what is the best practice for deleting objects along the way?

I understand the erase-remove idiom.  But since the vector contains pointers, I am concerned that this will only delete the pointer, but leave the instances hanging around in memory.

For example, I would do something like

```
std::vector<someClass*> someClassList
std::vector<someClass*>::iterator i;

for (i=someClassList.begin(); i != someClassList.end(); ++i){
    determine_if_should_be_deleted(i);
    // <--How to delete the object and remove it from the vector without 
    // <--messing up the iterator?
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use smart pointers here?

Comment: with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<someClass>>`, you may simply use erase-remove idiom.

Comment: Only use *non-owning* raw pointers in STL containers, i.e. if you use them as references. If the container needs to own the resources use a smart pointer (except `auto_ptr`) or one of [Boost's pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you used `new` to create each instance, then

`delete *i;`

will do the job. You won't mess up your iteration since you're not removing the *pointer* from the vector, but you're releasing the memory that's being pointed to.

A better technique would be to use `std::unique_ptr` though, then the `std::vector` destructor will take care of releasing memory.